# Importing BlobDomain package not found

Tags: java, image, import, package

I am trying to upload a image to SQLite DB in an ADF mobile application using the code below. i tried to import `BLOBDomain` with  `import oracle.jbo.domain.BlobDomain;` , the package was not found.

```
private BlobDomain createBlobDomain(File file){  
        InputStream in = null;
        BlobDomain blobDomain = null;
        OutputStream out = null;
        try
        {
            in = file.getInputStream();   
            blobDomain = new BlobDomain();
            out = blobDomain.getBinaryOutputStream();
            IOUtils.copy(in, out);
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (SQLException e)
        {
            e.fillInStackTrace();
        }
        return blobDomain;
}
```

What is the right package i should be using to import `BlobDomain` or does anyone know a better way to store image to SQLite database in ADF application?

Source:
http://tompeez.wordpress.com/2011/11/26/jdev11-1-2-1-0-handling-imagesfiles-in-adf-part-2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to include Bc4jdomorcl.jar to the library.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. How Can I import Bc4jdomorcl.jar?

Comment: Copy it from <jdev_install>/bc4j/lib, to the application server's /lib directory.